# Trying to point my domain to new VPS (with ISPConfig 3)

Tags: domain, centos7, vps, dns-zone

Rewrote for clarity: I got a CentOS 7 VPS and installed ISPConfig 3. I set the nameservers for my preexisting domain to those provided by my VPS hosting, and added the domain in ISPC3. The client is not set (in the settings for the domain in ISPC3) because it's my website. However it says when trying to access my domain that the IP cannot be found. What am I doing wrong? How to do this right?

Update: I added a DNS zone as per [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-run-your-own-name-server-with-ispconfig-3-and-fast-hosts) (sans FastHosts) but no records appeared upon its creation and I cannot set my domain's nameservers to them, won't let me.

Comment: The question is around, “I set my nameservers for my preexisting domain to those provided by my VPS hosting.” The nameservers your vps hosting provided would be for your vps server to resolve dns names. You wouldn’t point your domain to the vps nameservers unless you are adding  your domain on their nameservers somehow. And that is completely separate from what you are doing with ispconfig. Instead you should point domain.com nameserver settings to your ispconfig IP, but this is a terrible idea and usually completely unsupported. You need 2 or more nameservers and they have to be approved.

Comment: whoa well ok thank you for that it's a step in the right direction; so what, do i set up nameservers thru ispconfig? I tried that the first time around and maybe I did it wrong idk

Comment: If you are trying to host your own DNS for your own domain (ie, you are example.com and you want ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com to be the servers of record) you need what are called "glue records" set up by your registrar.  And you need 2 IPs, not just 2 names pointing to one IP.

Comment: well there's got to be a way to host a website on just my single vps right just how do I go about doing that